# Testing pdist() for statistical significance

Tags: r, sequence-analysis, traminer, vlmc, pst

Using `pdist()` in the [`PST package`](https://www.jstatsoft.org/index.php/jss/article/view/v072i03/v72i03.pdf), two probabilistic suffix trees (PSTs) can be compared to each other. The function will output a value for the degree of divergence between two fitted PSTs. However, how can this value be tested for statistical significance, to see whether it comes from a population where the value is greater than 0?

```
library(TraMineR)
library(PST)

a <- seqdef("A-A-A-B-B-C")
b <- seqdef("C-C-C-B-B-A")

a_pst <- pstree(a, ymin = 0.001, lik = FALSE, with.missing = FALSE)
b_pst <- pstree(b, ymin = 0.001, lik = FALSE, with.missing = FALSE)

pdist(a_pst, b_pst, l = 10, ns = 1000, symetric = TRUE, output = "mean")
```

Would it be sufficient to do:

```
output <- pdist(a_pst, b_pst, l = 10, ns = 1000, symetric = TRUE, output = "all")
t.test(output)
```

?

Comment: you have introduced new tags pst and vlmc.  Can you please add tag wikis?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen done--we can delete these comments now.

Answer (score 0):

A t-test is probably not appropriate because the divergence can only be positive.

You may find a statistical test for the divergence between two PST models in [Christine Largeron (2003)](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Prediction-suffix-trees-for-supervised-classificat-Largeron/29ea9936395e2f09bc0c9429dbf4210e1df7aca3).